# Storing adress to stack allocated object in vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm having trouble with storing pointers to adresses for stack allocated objects in vectors. Somehow the pointers seem to overwrite one another in ways I do not understand.

In my main I want to read from a file, create Nodes (stack allocated) and put them in a vector. Later I continue to read from the file to create connections (Edges) between the Nodes and thus stack allocate Edge objects and try to store the adresses to these in respective Node (Nodes contain a vector). The input file is on the format index_1 a, index_2, b, capacity c which means that an Edge from a to b and vice versa is to be created, with capacity c.

Every time I add an Edge to a Node (vector::push_back()) the entire vector in the Node is set to the same pointer (instead of just appending another pointer, as intended). Example output after adding 3 Edges to the same Node:

```
#0 named: ORIGINS connected to: 
#1 named: 2, capacity: -1, flow: 0

#0 named: ORIGINS connected to: 
#17 named: 3W, capacity: -1, flow: 0
#17 named: 3W, capacity: -1, flow: 0

#0 named: ORIGINS connected to: 
#16 named: 3E, capacity: -1, flow: 0
#16 named: 3E, capacity: -1, flow: 0
#16 named: 3E, capacity: -1, flow: 0
```

Excuse my code if there are any tests or prints left in it:

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include "Edge.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Node& obj) {
    os << "#" << obj.index << " named: " << obj.name << " connected to: " << endl;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < obj.edges.size(); ++i) {
        Edge* e = obj.edges[i];
        os << "#" << e->getEndNode()->getIndex() << " named: " << e->getEndNode()->getName() << ", capacity: " << e->getCapacity() << ", flow: " << e->getFlow() << endl;
    }
    return os;
}

int main() {
    string fileName = "rail.txt";

    //open file
    ifstream infile(fileName.c_str());

    //initialize variables
    string line;
    vector<Node> graph;

    int n;
    getline(infile, line);
    n = atoi(line.c_str());
    //read n nodes
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (getline(infile, line)) {
            Node node(line, i);
            graph.push_back(node);
        } else {
            cout << "Error in parsing nodes" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    int m;
    getline(infile, line);
    m = atoi(line.c_str());
    //read m edges
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        if (getline(infile, line)) {
            istringstream iss(line);
            int a, b, c;

            iss >> a >> b >> c;
            Edge e1(&graph[b], c, 0);
            Edge e2(&graph[a], c, 0);
            graph[a].addEdge(&e1);
            graph[b].addEdge(&e2);
            cout << graph[a] << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Error in parsing edges" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /*for (auto e : graph[0].getEdges()) {
        cout << e->getEndNode()->getName() << endl;
    }*/


    return 0;
}
```

Edge.cpp:

```
#include "Edge.h"

Edge::Edge() : endNode(nullptr), capacity(0), flow(0) {};
Edge::Edge(Node* n, int c, int f) : endNode(n), capacity(c), flow(f) {};
Edge::Edge(const Edge& other) {
    endNode = other.endNode;
    capacity = other.capacity;
    flow = other.flow;
};

bool Edge::pushFlow(int f) {
    if (flow + f <= capacity) {
        flow += f;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

bool Edge::popFlow(int f) {
    if (flow - f >= 0) {
        flow -= f;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

Node* Edge::getEndNode() {
    return endNode;
}

int Edge::getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
}

int Edge::getFlow() {
    return flow;
}
```

Node.cpp:

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <iostream>
Node::Node() : name(""), index(-1) {};
Node::Node(std::string n, int i) : name(n), index(i) {};
Node::Node(const Node& other) : name(other.name), index(other.index), edges(other.edges) {};

void Node::addEdge(Edge* e) {
    edges.push_back(e);
}

std::vector<Edge*> Node::getEdges() {
    return edges;
}

Node& Node::operator=(const Node& rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs) return *this;
    name = rhs.name;
    index = rhs.index;
    edges = rhs.edges;
    return *this;
}

std::string Node::getName() {
    return name;
}

int Node::getIndex() {
    return index;
}
```

Thank you for any help or pointer (he he)!

Comment: Stack allocated instances will be destroyed as soon they go out of scope, so it's certainly not a very good idea to use their addresses further outside of that scope.

Comment: In future questions please do reduce your code to a **minimal but complete example** that readers can try out.

Comment: Suppose the sports car of your dreams is parked at 1428, Elm Street. The following day, you meet a good friend and you say "Go to 1428, Elm Street and look at my dream car". He returns and says "Why do you dream of a garbage truck? You need help". Do you understand how that could happen?

Comment: @molbdnilo Your comment makes me remember a friend who used to flag his car parking place with a fancy car near it... He usually spends hours looking for it later..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as execution leaves the scope a non-`static` variable is declared in, that variable ceases to exist, and pointers to it become **dangling pointers**.

A dangling pointer is **invalid**. Even just inspecting the value can cause a hardware trap. Therefore any use of it is Undefined Behavior.

And so that's what you have, because you do things like

```
graph[a].addEdge(&e1);
```

in a loop where `e1` is a variable declared in the loop body.

Comment: I see. So you have to heap allocate everything?

Comment: @Pkaff that pushes a copy of your node so that is fine.

Comment: @Pkaff Change your vector to keep Edge not pointers to Edge. If pointers are necessary, you have to dynamically allocate them.